# Load mustache files on visualforce

Tags: visualforce, html

I'd like to move *.mustache code to static resources folder /views/*.mustache and load it on the page like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="casesView" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.styles, '/views/casesView.html')}">
</script>

<script type="text/mustache" id="casesView" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.styles, '/views/casesView.mustache')}">
</script>
```

But this resuls in error with type="text/mustache"

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream
```

or in case of type="text/html"

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

Is it possible to fix on salesforce?

Comment: Try changing the type to text/mustache?

Comment: Are you sure that your template should be a html file ?

Comment: I've tried with both html and mustache file and the error is the same

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to use the javascript mimetype (`application/javascript`).

Comment: With such mimetype there is the error:'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

Answer (score 1):

You can't add javascript templates in javascript resource file like this. I suggest you, to create apex component and include it inside VF.